# oracleで下記のようなSQL文をwhere句に入れて、case文に導入して条件分岐させたいです。

Tags: sql, oracle

oracleで下記のようなSQL文をwhere句に入れて、case文に導入して条件分岐させたいです。

前提事項として下記のようなカラムが存在
A=ID最終利用日
B=ID登録日
C=ID公開日

下記のようなwhere句に入れて、case文に導入して条件分岐させたいSQL

Aのカラムがnull でなければAのカラムを参照
Aのカラムがnull and 公開日 > 登録日 であれば 公開日を参照
Aのカラムがnull and 発売日 < 登録日 であれば 登録日を参照

上記のようなSQLをwhere句に入れて、case文に導入してから条件分岐させたいのですが、
where句に入れて、case文では上記に沿う文法が解らずうまくいきません。

上記のようなアルゴリズムを導入するのに適したoracleでの文法を教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

where句でcase文が使えますので、`A,B,C`カラムをwhere句のcase文でご参照ください。
上記のようなアルゴリズムを導入するのに適したoracleでの文法は`nvl`と`greatest`を併用して、Aがない時はBとCの大きい値を参照する方法です。
ただし質問文の条件ではBとCが同値の場合の挙動が記述されていませんので、要求に合わせた改修をお願いいたします。

```
select nvl(A, greatest(B, C)) as NVL_GREATEST,
       case when A is null then
            case when B > C then B
                 when B < C then C
                 else null          -- この行はなくても同じ
            end
            else A
       end  CASE_NEST
from  (select to_date('2019/01/01') as A, to_date('2019/11/02') as B, to_date('2019/11/03') as C from dual union all -- Aが存在
       select null                  as A, to_date('2019/11/02') as B, to_date('2009/01/03') as C from dual union all -- Bが大きい
       select null                  as A, to_date('2009/01/02') as B, to_date('2019/11/03') as C from dual union all -- Cが大きい
       select null                  as A, to_date('2019/11/11') as B, to_date('2019/11/11') as C from dual           -- BとCが同値
      )
where sysdate > case when A is null then
                     case when B > C then B
                          when B < C then C
                          else null
                     end
                     else A
                end
--where sysdate > nvl(A, greatest(B, C))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、参考にさせていただきます。